# Check value in array at specific index?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having a bit of trouble with something....

Basicly I have this array (2 dimensional) that stores tiles (basic div's with colors etc...), one may change the properties of a specific tile by doing;

```
world[x][y].style blabla somehting
```

Now, I'm starting to do a bit of pathfinding to be able to walk around on these tiles, lets say I have a 10x10 grid of tiles, ranging from -5,-5 to 5,5 (in coordinates).

I'm sitting on the -5,-5 tile and I click somewhere to "start the pathfinding", my pathfinding  thing basicly just finds the 8 adjacent tiles and returns them, then I select the one that brings me closer and I do that X amount of times till I hit my target.

This is no problem if I stand in the middle (0,0) and try to go somewhere, but since I'm in the corner of my "world" I get a few problems when searching for the adjacent tiles;

--# o o o o--

--o o o o o--

--o o o o o--

--o o o o o--

--o o o o o--

Lets say this is my world, # being the character, o being empty tiles and - just being an empty abyss (places where I can't be)

Now I want to go to X;

--# o o o o--

--o o o o o--

--o o X o o--

--o o o o o--

--o o o o o--

So I start my little pathfinding algorithm but when it searches for adjacent tiles from where I am, it returns an error since there is no tiles left, left+down, left+up, or up (from my position.

--# + o o o--

--+ + o o o--

--o o o o o--

--o o o o o--

--o o o o o--

(+) is the tiles that are available but it tries to search for more tiles around me, which results in an error.

I've tried to disclude tiles that doesn't exist by using;

```
if (world[x][y] !== null) {}
if (world[x][y] != null) {}
if (world[x][y] !== 'undefined') {}
if (world[x][y] != 'undefined') {}
if (!world[x][y]) {}
```

But then the error is given at the if statement instead of the actuall "tile returning"...

So, how do I precheck if there's something in the array at a specific index (or 2 specific indexe's)?

Also please note that my array does have some gaps, since my world is not only walkable tiles.

Comment: if (typeof world[x][y] != 'undefined') {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to validate the row/column at `world[x]` before checking `world[x][y]`

```
if (!world[x] || !world[x][y]) {
    // Tile does not exist
}else{
    // Tile exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you type this line in to your console all by itself:

```
console.log(typeof x); //output: undefined
```

without ever having defined any element named 'x', the statement will evaluate to 'undefined'.

Potentially then you can use *typeof* in your if...else statements to check for an undefined type (which would be the type of something that doesn't exist yet.)

Answer (score 0):

One effective way of solving this problem is to make the world one "ring" wider (12x12 instead of 10x10) with empty-abyss tokens in all outer tiles. Now the character will never test undefined tiles and your algo will work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you check the indices (x and y) before asking for the "tile". If you can afford requiring a tile to be returned a little algorithm checking whether what directions can have a tile to be returned seems not very hard.

As a suggestion, you could write a function that returns the actual "neighboring/adjacent" tiles _using_the_index_values_, taking into account that there are no tiles "left" of -5 or "right of +5, etc.

That would mean that not all "neighboring tiles" arrays will have the same amount of tiles, but you can easily manipulate, traverse, know the length (of) etc and array.

If I had more details of the "pathfinding algorithm" I might be able to write sample code. (Hope it helps.)